# 1 Kings 18 Obadiah and Elijah

Tags: exegesis, elijah, 1-kings, obadiah

I am writing a short story based on 1 Kings 18, and I was wondering if the servant mention in verses 43 and onwards is Obadiah or not.

In verse 9, Obadiah refers to himself as Elijah's servant.

> 9 ‘What have I done wrong,’ asked Obadiah, ‘that you are handing your servant over to Ahab to be put to death?

The servant that Elijah is with later on, however, wasn't named.

> 43 ‘Go and look toward the sea,’ he told his servant.

Are they one and the same, or two different people?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). I hope you get some good answers to your question. Please do stick around and browse some of the other questions and answers here as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [gwofatlanta's conclusion](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/48751/10486) and would put it in even stronger terms - **it is highly unlikely that the servant in 1 Kings 18 refers to Obadiah**.

- Firstly, "your servant" was a common polite form of address in biblical times, and it is [extremely common for it to be used in this non-literal sense](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=%22your%20servant%22&qs_version=NIV).
- Secondly Obadiah is specifically described as a palace administrator (18:3), so technically,if anyone's, he would have been regarded as King Ahab's "servant", and **he would have been using the phrase "your servant" non-literally**.
- In order for him to have become the literal servant referred to later in chapter 18 and in chapter 19, verse 3, he would have to either: have been dismissed; have resigned; or have abandoned his previous position, and there is no mention of any of those things happening whatsoever.
- Finally as [gwofatlanta has already argued](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/48751/10486) after being mentioned by name in chapter 18, it is unlikely he would not continue to be identified by name in the later episodes of the narrative.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. This unnamed servant was left in Beersheba by Elijah ( I Kings 19:3). After naming Obadiah specifically and detailing his conversation with Elijah in the first half of I Kings 18, it would be unreasonable not to name him in the interactions with Elijah later on, if had been Obadiah again.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for offering an answer. For some further tips on writing good answers here, see: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer) Please feel free to look around for other questions and answers that might be of interest to you.